# How to send json from html form

Tags: html, json, spring, kotlin

I am trying to send a form represented as JSON from my HTML code:

```
<form action="/login/verify" enctype="application/json" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="login" name="login"><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My example Kotlin code:

```
@PostMapping("/login/verify")
fun log(@RequestBody user: User, model: Model) {
    model["title"] = "login Verify"
    model["login"] = user.login
}


data class User(val login: String, val password: String)
```

I known `enctype="application/json"` doesn't work but what can I use, do I need to use javascript?

EDIT:

I'm wrote this js:

```
 function sendJSON(formName) {
var myForm  = document.getElementById(formName);
var data = {};
    for(var formElement of myForm.childNodes.values()){
    if(formElement.name!= "undefined")
    {
        var key = formElement.name
        var value = formElement.value

        data[key] = value
    }
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", myForm.action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

and i change an input type from submit to button and I add there onclick, but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to include some client-side JavaScript to send the POST data in the form as a JSON object.

You can do this by creating a JavaScript `function` that is called `onclick` of the submit button which does the following:

1. Access the form data through the DOM
2. Access the key-value pairs of the form data
3. Convert the object to JSON
4. Send a POST, for example using `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser doesn't support the JSON type. Looks like only support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, `text/plain`
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype)

So what I recommend is using javascript. I found good library for this case.
https://github.com/keithhackbarth/submitAsJSON

Comment: i'm check it, js support this content -type ->'application/json; charset=UTF-8' but only in POST

Answer (score -1):

My script is good but, this request get, a 404 response and don't move to next page it's can be checked by xhr.responsetext